# Does dying your hair navy blue (which looks black) come under the ruling of dying your hair black?

Tags: halal-haram, hair, dyeing-hair

Salaam, I’ve read that black hair dye is forbidden in Islam- those who do will not even smell the scent of paradise however i read that black mixed with another colour is fine, so does navy (a dark blue that looks black) suffice?

Comment: The King of Saudi Arabia has black hair (as did all the other "old" kings going back to King Fahd) even though he is 81 years old and obviously uses dye (unless you want to claim a miracle). It is highly unlikely that he would do this publicly if it was forbidden.

Comment: There are many things that rulers in Arabia do that are not supported in Islam. A ruling in Islam comes from Quran and Sunnah ; not from what the elites have interpreted them to be.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you read correctly that black hair dye is forbidden in Islam.

Now the question is -

- 'Is 1% less than pure black ok?' or
- 'Dark blue that looks black ok?'
  etc.

As per the intent of the law, one must avoid any color that appears black. 
Also, since the hadith is very strong with phrase '**they will not even smell the fragrance of Paradise**', it is better to avoid anything that is close to black or looks like black.

This is my opinion.

Allah knows best!

Comment: Black hair dye was not recommended by Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) only for the very old age person named Abu Qahafa who was the father of Abu Bakr. Scholars argue that, the reason why it was not recommended was because Abu Qahafa was very old, and his face was wrinkled. Dying an old person with a wrinkled face with black does not look natural and therefore, the prophet asked to dye it with a colour other than black. However, that does not make black dye haram for everyone else, because nowhere is it mentioned that black dye is haram

Comment: @QaisarKhan, which scholars say the prohibition of dying in black is only limited to old people and that the reason is it would not look natural. Can you please provide the references?

Comment: @III-AK-III It is against the policy of this site to ask questions in comments.